# New pull request without unmerged commits

Tags: git, github

I have a pull request on a repository. The commits are still unmerged. Now, I want to make another pull request, totally independent from the previous one. When I create a new branch and make the new commits, all of the unmerged commits are also alongside with the new ones!

I want to create a new pull request without the unmerged commits. Please help me on how should I do that as I'm new to git :)

Comment: Not 100% sure... But `git stash` can come in handy. As can `git checkout -b newBranchName` You'll want to be on the master branch when you do that. It sounds like you're making a new branch from the branch with the pull request instead of making a new branch from the master branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I create a new branch and make the new commits

This is the source of your problem.  Instead of adding commits to the same feature branch, you should create a new branch from the current feature's parent and commit from there.  Let's say the parent branch is `master` and the feature branch has 3 commits in it.  The diagram would look like this:

```
master:  ... A -- B -- C
                   \
feature:            M -- N -- O
```

When you created a new branch from `feature` and started adding new commits you ended up with this:

```
master:  ... A -- B -- C
                   \
feature:            M -- N -- O
                               \
new_ft:                         S -- T ...
```

In other words, the history of `feature` is part of the new branch.  Instead, you can create a new branch from the `B` commit in `master` using:

```
git checkout -b new_feature <SHA-1 for commit B>
```

Now make your other set of commits, and then this second pull request will be essentially independent from the first one.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your quick response, I appreciate it :) I create the branch from my fork; If that's wrong, then how should I create a new bracnh, may be a new fork?!!

Comment: @goodUser Spot on, create a new branch from the point where you had intended it to start.

Comment: I'll try it out, so I should *not* create the new branch from my current fork, should I?!!

Comment: Not unless you want those other commits still there.

Comment: It is almost always a good idea to branch from master. For that you have to checkout the master first and create your new branches from there. Look at my answer.

Comment: @jschnasse This depends on what the OP wants.  Newer commits may have come into `master` between when `feature` was created and when he intended to create the second branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you're right! It is just the most common model to branch up from master and to created pull requests against the master. Also it is sensible to ask commiters to rebase to current version of master before doing a pull request.

Comment: I really appreciate your time to answer the question, that's what I need and I've got the idea :) besides the way you've introduced, I already have forked the repository on GitHub and it seems I cannot have multiple forks simultaneously there to do it without the commands :( _or am I wrong?_ and it seems I **do** have to dive into the command line git!:o

Comment: Yes, use the command line! The idea is (1) fork on github (2) Clone from origin to your computer (2) Add your fork as a remote. (3) Push new branches to your fork. (4) Make pull requests from your fork to the origin master

Comment: I agree with @jschnasse ... use the Git bash for this 100%, this is a good time to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You probably created your branch not from master but from your recent feature branch.
To branch from your master you must first checkout the master.

This is what I would do.

## 0. Example Project setup and workflow

(1) fork on github (2) Clone origin to your computer (2) Add your fork as a remote. (3) Push new branches to your fork. (4) Make pull requests from your fork to the origin master

Look up [github workflow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) as an example of a well tested approach.

## 1. Keep your local master in sync to origin

Go back to your master

```
git checkout master
```

Often it is a good idea to sync it to the origin

```
git pull origin master
```

Make sure that everything is like expected

```
git log
git status
```

## 2. branch from master

Now create your branch

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

## 3. Add commits to your branch

Now look up the commits in your original branch

```
git log old_branch_with_to_many_commits
```

All commits have a hash. You can use those numbers to cherry-pick single commits into your new_branch. So copy the hash of first commit you want to keep into your clipboard.

Now use git cherry-pick to get single commits into your new_branch one by one

```
git cherry-pick a_commit_hash
...
git cherry-pick next_commit_hash
```

## 4. Clean up your old branch

Now you might want to clean the commits from your old branch.

```
git checkout old_branch_with_to_many_commits
```

Lookup the hash of the last commit you want to keep

```
git log
```

Copy the hash to reset the branch

```
git reset --hard hash_of_the_last_commit_you_want_to_keep
```

Comment: We're not done with cherry picking if you want to explain that part as well, because afterwards those new commits need to be nuked or reverted.

Comment: I added that part as well.

Comment: But be careful: If the branch might be shared, then you would want to `git revert` instead of nuking (though probably unlikely here).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Create Satsh which will temporary store you commits in some storage

```
git stash
```

Then create a new brnach

```
git checkout -b "new branch name".
```

Then get all that commits in the new branch by poping the stash

```
git stash pop
```

all commit which is in old branch will be saved here.

or else
If you want to commit and all changes are also committed to new branch so simply just commit all changes in that branch and make a new branch.

```
git checkout -b "new branch"
```

as you created new branch from previous branch all changes are taken in new branch

Comment: The commits are already commited - as far as I understood. So `stash` wouldn't help.