# How to create a branch on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repository on GitHub and committed some new features on my **master** fork branch that are not merged yet; so my fork master branch is not clean (I mean it has some commits waiting to be merged), thus I cannot make any **independently** new pull requests to the repository by adding a new branch, because the previous unmerged commits will come along the new ones, and it seems you cannot have multiple forks simultaneously :(

I already [know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44450122/5222086) that I can create a new branch using the following code, in for example the GitBash:

```
git checkout -b new_feature <SHA-1 for commit>
```

Logically it should be involved with the cloning of the repository locally and then uploading *(or whatever the term is)* to the remote server. I don't know the procedures to achieve that! As a beginner, the online [documentations](https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/wiki/Create-a-new-branch-with-git-and-manage-branches) look too vague to me.

So please help me on how I may create a **new** branch on the *remote server* (I already have a cluttered fork) *to be appeared under my account on GitHub,* possibly without cloning it locally?

---

P.S. If you don't have time to explain it, I think I can figure it out by studding the **appropriate** git statements you provide :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this command is not working for you. After having a lot of troublesome period with git, I had normalised a procedure to do this :

**1-** Set url of origin :

```
         git remote set-url origin http://bitbucket.org/xyz.git
```

**2-**  Update git

```
         git remote update
```

**3-** Commit your code

```
         git add -A
         git commit -a -m "message"
```

**4-** Create branch

```
         git checkout -b BRANCH_NAME
```

**5-** Push to branch

```
         git push origin BRANCH_NAME
```

If you still get an error from git i.e *origin is behind by 2 commits, pull from origin to resolve*. You can try following command to push your code to branch anyway.

**5-** Force Push

```
         git push -f origin BRANCH_NAME
```

Hope it helps. :)

Please confirm that a branch does not exist with same name.

If having trouble try creating a branch from console and change your origin via 1st command.